# cmake source directory does not contain cmake lists

Tags: emokit

I am trying to install emokit on an Ubuntu partition of my macbook pro.
 I am up to step 48 in [the instructions](https://github.com/qdot/emokit/blob/master/INSTALL#L19), when I receive an error:

```
matt@MattsUbuntu:~/Downloads/emokit-master$ cmake .
```

> CMake Error: The source directory "/home/matt/Downloads/emokit-master" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
>   Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

What can I do to complete this step?

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the maintainers of emokit. First off, you're running off my personal fork, not the main repo. The main repo for the C code is at

http://github.com/openyou/emokit-c

The python repo is now

http://github.com/openyou/emokit

That changed in May 2016, so it's a fairly recent deal. We decided to keep the regular 'emokit' as python because most emokit users aren't touching the C libraries.

For any other questions you may have, just file issues in the emokit-c repo and I'll do what I can, though I'm WAY behind on it right now.

Comment: Yup! There's no more cmake files in the python repo, since python doesn't really need a build system. They're all in the C repo now.

Comment: I could not find the installation instructions for the updated python version. Can you link this?

Comment: Not sure there _are_ installation instructions. It should be installable from pypi via pip now, via "pip install emokit". But I'm not the package maintainer anymore so I can't get you much farther than that. You might try filing github bugs about this if you can't find what you're looking for.

Comment: It says "hidapi will still need to be installed manually on Linux and OS X.". I think pypi is just for the windows version. I asked for the instructions on the github page, thank you!